# Update Google Play services for an old app

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an old app which uses Google play services 5.08. Since the app uses kiosk mode, we never updated google play services on the device. Now I have to update the google play services to 8.4. I also want the already existing users to use the app without getting crashes. So how do I support both of 5.08 and 8.4 APIs to support in the app? I see Google doesn't expose the APIs of 5.08 when I use 8.4 in Gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a newer version of the app that will use the latest google play service(8.4). Retain the older version of the app for the current google play service(5.08).

The version of the Google Play Service will depend on the APIs your application implements. Supporting both google play service in an app will affect your application performance in a negative way or it is not applicable. Every update of Google Play service adds new APIs connected and older APIs improved. Consider the APIs your application will implement, then decide which version of google play services should  your user update to have a smooth running application.

> [**The Google Play services client
>    library**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview#how_it_works)
>
> The client library contains the interfaces to the individual Google
>    services and allows you to obtain authorization from users to gain
>    access to these services with their credentials. **It also contains APIs
>    that allow you to resolve any issues at runtime, such as a missing,
>    disabled, or out-of-date Google Play services APK.** The client library
>    has a light footprint if you use
>    [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) as
>    part of your build process, so it won't have an adverse impact on your
>    app's file size.
>
> **If you want to access added features or products, you can upgrade to a
>    new version of the client library as they are released. However,
>    upgrading is not necessary if you don't care about new features or bug
>    fixes.** We anticipate more Google services to be continuously added, so
>    be on the lookout for these updates.